# System Assigned identity failed to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, microsoft-entra-id

I have a .NET App Service running which is using Entity Framework to connect to an Azure SQL Server database.

The SQL Server is set to only allow connections from Microsoft Entra.

Steps taken:

1. Upload Web API to App Service in Azure

   - My app has the following connectionstring:
     `Server=tcp:acme-dev-db.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=acme-db-test;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication="Active Directory Default";`
2. Enabled System Assigned Identity on App Service
3. Ran the following query through SSMS on my database `acme-db-test`

```
   CREATE USER [acme-myapp-api-t] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
   ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [acme-myapp-api-t];
   ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [acme-myapp-api-t];
   ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [acme-myapp-api-t];
```

4. Ensured that "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" is set to "Yes" from the Azure Portal under the Sql Server\Security\Firewalls and virtual networks

As far as I know this should be enough to allow my Web API to connect to the SQL Server database. But when I try to start my application in the App Service I get the following error back:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.

I used the same approach for the `dev` App Service with the name `acme-myapp-api-d`, and it worked fine for that resource. The only difference is that the `dev` App Service connects to a different database (`acme-db`), but on the same SQL Server instance.

Anyone any idea why I am getting this `Login failed` error for the `test` App Service?

---

## Update 1:

When I change my connectionstring to connect to the `dev` database `acme-db` then it all works fine. I also ran the query above to add my App Service as `EXTERNAL PROVIDER`.

But for some reason it doesn't connect the second database I created. Still no idea why.

## Update 2:

I deleted the database and re-created it, ran the query to add the resource as EXTERNAL PROVIDER and it worked.

The only thing I changed was that the database was a development database, and now I switched to a serverless production database.

Not sure if you can't connect to a development database using Entra ID, but it works when now.

Comment: Make sure test app service has access to the database otherwise give access to the test app service using above mentioned code

Comment: https://medium.com/@kamaleshs48/sql-login-using-azure-manage-identity-in-c-7b2dd93ecc01 have you checke this documnet?

Comment: check this document https://blog.novanet.no/passwordless-connectionstring-to-azure-sql-database-using-managed-identity/ if it helps you.

Comment: @PratikLad Yes I checked both documents and as far as I can tell I did exactly what they described. I even changed the connectionstring so that it is in the format of the documentation. But similar error: `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'`